# xampp tomcat not working

Tags: tomcat, xampp

My instance of xampp tomcat is not starting, but localhost:8080 is working properly. My xampp control panel looks like

[image]

```
Problem detected!
9:37:45 PM  [Tomcat]    Port 8080 in use by "C:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe"!
9:37:45 PM  [Tomcat]    Tomcat WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
9:37:45 PM  [Tomcat]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
9:37:45 PM  [Tomcat]    or reconfigure Tomcat and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the Apache module is using the port `8080`. So the same port can't be used by Tomcat.

You have the following possibilities:

- **change the port of Apache**, maybe you want to use port `80` instead of `8080` for the Apache server.
- **change the port of Tomcat**, maybe you want to use another port instead of the default port `8080` for the Tomcat server.
- **disable Apache** if you don't want / have to use the Apache web server.

Answer (score 0):

```
Tomcat Started/Stopped with errors, return code: 1
Make sure you have Java JDK or JRE installed and the required ports are free
Check the "/xampp/tomcat/logs" folder for more information
```

**How to do repair started catalina from tomcat in xampp?**

Maybe your problem is in file catalina_start.bat
I found broken path registry for JDK in this file:

```
Line 12: set KeyName=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit
```

change to:

```
Line 12: set KeyName=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\JDK
```

and now it`s working server tomcat